# assign a string variable to html <option value=....> tag

Tags: javascript, html

i want to pass a string value which change dynamically.how can i assign that to a option value=... tag 
likehere first option vaue is working properly but i want to pass diff name every time so how can i pass that string variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test="117960298357503_22120.mp4";
</script>

<OPTION value="J:\Users\ADITYARAJ SINGH\Downloads\Video\117960298357503_22120.mp4">My Video File </OPTION>
<OPTION value="J:\Users\ADITYARAJ SINGH\Downloads\Video\('+ test +')">My Video1 File </OPTION>
```

Comment: Rephrase your question with more information (e.g. HOW, WHEN, & WHERE do you want to change it?).  It makes no sense as is.

Answer (score 0):

Give your option an id, then get it with jquery and set the value of it:

The HTML Markup:

```
<OPTION value="J:\Users\ADITYARAJ SINGH\Downloads\Video\117960298357503_22120.mp4">My Video File </OPTION>
<OPTION value="" id="myoption">My Video1 File </OPTION>
```

and the script:

```
$(function () {
    var test = "117960298357503_22120.mp4";
    $('#myoption').attr('value', 'J:\Users\ADITYARAJ SINGH\Downloads\Video\' + test);
});
```